# $w^k$ and $w^{n-k}$ are conjugate and inverse of each other

Tags: proof-verification, complex-numbers, proof-writing

This is my first proof class and I'm struggling with the complex chapter. Please tell me if my proof is correct, or needs help.

Let $w=e^{2\pi i/n}$ where $n\in \mathbb{Z}>0$ and prove that $w^k$ and $w^{n-k}$ are conjugate and inverse of each other $\forall k\in\mathbb{Z}:0\leq k\leq n-1$.

I found that,

$w^k=e^{2k\pi i/n}\implies \cos\frac{2k\pi}{n}+i\sin\frac{2k\pi}{n}$.

Also,

$w^{n-k}=e^{\frac{2\pi i}{n}\cdot n-k}=e^{2\pi i}e^{-\frac{2k\pi i}{n}}=e^{-\frac{2k\pi i}{n}}=\cos\left(-\frac{2k\pi}{n}\right)+i\sin\left(-\frac{2k\pi}{n}\right)=\cos\left(\frac{2k\pi}{n}\right)-i\sin\left(\frac{2k\pi}{n}\right)$ .

So, $w^k$ and $w^{n-k}$ are conjugates. However, this is where I am a little confused, to prove they are inverse of each other can I simply say:

\begin{equation} 
\frac{1}{w^k}=w^{n-k}\implies \frac{1}{w^k}=w^nw^{-k}\implies w^n=1
\end{equation}

which is true; therefore, the equality $\frac{1}{w^k}=w^{n-k}$ is also true by direct proof?

Comment: Second part no.  That is assuming what you want to prove and not getting a contradiction.  That's not valid.  (If birds are elephants then birds breath.  ANd birds *do* breath.  So birds are elephants).  But you can do $w^k*w^{n-k} = w^n = 1$.  That *is* a direct proof.

Comment: You can use the fact that  for any $w\in \Bbb C$ we have $|w|=1$ iff   $\bar w=1/w.$ For if $a,b\in \Bbb R$ and $w=a+bi$ then $|w|=1\iff |w|^2=1\iff$ $ a^2+b^2=1\iff$ $ ( (a+bi)(a-bi)=1)\iff$ $  w\bar w=1 \iff$ $ \bar w=1/w.$.... And deMoivre'sTheorem: $(\cos t +i\sin t)^n=\cos nt +\sin nt$, for any $n\in \Bbb N,$ implies $(\cos 2\pi /n+i\sin 2\pi /n)^n=1.$ ...Or that $(\exp z)^n=\exp (nz)$ for all complex $z$ and all $n\in \Bbb N$ (if you already have this), to show $w^n=1.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first part is perfect.

For the second one, $w^k w^{n-k}= e^{\frac{2\pi k i}{n}}e^{\frac{2\pi (n-k)i}{n}}=e^{\frac{2\pi k i}{n} +\frac{2\pi (n-k)i}{n}}=e^{\frac{2\pi n i}{n}}=e^{2\pi i}=1$

Comment: Thank you, it makes sense now

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* If $a$ and $b$ are multiplicative inverses of each other then $a.b=1=$(multiplicative identity).

Comment: Thank you, i guess i was just misinterpreting the question

Comment: You were thinking "$a$ and $b$ are inverse" means "$a = \frac 1b$".  Technically the definition of $\frac 1b$ is "the number $c$ so that $ac = 1$".  So "$a = \frac 1b$" and "$ab = 1$" are eqivalent statements. (This assumes $b\ne 0$.)  It doesn't matter which you try to prove.  You could do $w^{n-k} = \frac {w^n}{w^k} = \frac 1{w^k}$ and that'd be just as good.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. That is exactly what I thought.